# Overwrite a column in one dataframe with one in another dataframe if the value for the entries in the second dataframe is among the top 50% in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I want to combine the 'gr' columns from dataframes A and B, using the top 50% of entries based on the 'value' column in dataframe B.

Essentially, I want to overwrite the 'gr' variable in dataframe A with the one in dataframe B if the value in dataframe B is in the top 50%.

Importantly, the top-to-bottom order of the 'sample' column must remain the same.

Here is some example data:

```
dataframe_A <- data.frame(sample = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
                              gr = c("1","2","3","3","2","1","4","4","4","3","2","5","1","4","3","4","5","5","1","2","2","3","4","5","1","2","2","3","4","4","5","5","2","1","3","5","3","2","2"))

dataframe_B <- data.frame(sample = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
                              gr = c("5","3","3","5","5","5","5","3","5","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","1","1","4","4","4","4","4","4"),
                              value = c("20.06915","20.06915","19.53556","19.39911","19.06339","18.35938","18.34701","17.85767","17.60714","17.30706","17.08515","16.91452","16.72728","16.46812","15.85850","15.42839","14.92798","14.65943","14.53258","14.33954","14.33583","14.23938","14.19658","14.12557","14.03669","13.89811","13.78137","13.75599","13.51798","13.41058","13.17932","13.11952","12.67316","12.57049","11.88663","11.08443","10.75299","10.61885","10.40393"))
```

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataframe_A)
setDT(dataframe_B)
dataframe_B[, value := as.numeric(value)]
dataframe_A[dataframe_B[value > median(value)], on = "sample", gr := i.gr]
```

Using `base R`:

```
dataframe_B$value <- as.numeric(dataframe_B$value)
dfb2update <- dataframe_B[with(dataframe_B, value > median(value)), c("sample", "gr")]
rowsdfa2update <- which(dataframe_A$sample %in% dfb2update$sample)
dataframe_A$gr[rowsdfa2update] <- dfb2update[match(dataframe_A$sample[rowsdfa2update], dfb2update$sample), "gr"]
```